# Present Perfect or Present Perfect Continuous with "throughout"

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

Which one is grammatical:

> Throughout my career, I have been writing a diverse range of computer programs for multiple employers.
>
> Throughout my career, I have written a diverse range of computer programs for multiple employers.

Why?

Comment: This has been repeated many times here: both are grammatical. It depends on what you want to say. The first implies you are still writing computer programs. The second implies you did this in the past ***without specifying when***.

Comment: They're both grammatically correct, but the first one sounds very odd to this US English speaker.  It sounds like you're trying to specify that at every point in your career, you were in the middle of writing a program.  Just use *have written*.

Answer (score 1):

> Throughout my career...

**I wrote**  means you are speaking about your career from the perspective of retirement or after a change in careers.  The career we're speaking about was entirely in the past.

**I have written**  means you are still within your current career, but want to highlight things you have done before "now" whether you are still doing them or not.

**I had written**  means you are discussing your career (or a past career) from the perspective of some time during the career — a time before "now."  And from that perspective, you wrote things.

**I have been writting**  means you are still within your current career and are still writting.  This is often used to highlight achievement in an ongoing aspect of an ongoing career.

**I had been writting**  doesn't make sense in this context.  It would suggest a condtion had been met or was expected during a previous period of time.  But that is not indicated in the rest of your example.  Think of it this way: "During my career I had been writting programs when suddenly I won the lottery and didn't need to anymore."

**I was writting**  also doesn't make sense in this context.  It would suggest a condition would be met sometime in the future from the perspective of a past time.  But that is not indicated in the rest of your example.  Think of it this way: "During my career I was writting programs because no one would hire me to do anything else."

*I apologize that I haven't taken the time to explain all the verb tenses and forms for these examples.  If you wish me to do so, please let me know, but I'll need to do it at a later time.  Also, note that this is a complex discussion and I've given you what is at best a two-dimensional overview.  My answer is the beginning of wisdom, not the end.*